# Rails custom includes in a multiple tables relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Girl < User
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :info, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :girl
end

class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :girl
end
```

I have to make a query using photos, and I also need to fetch informations about the girl and I want to eager load info for those girl who has is (it is not mandatory for all the the girls to have it).

I want something similar to `Photo.joins(:girl).includes(:info)` but when I try to do it, it (obviously) try to associate the info with the photo table, causing this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'info' was not found on Photo; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

How can I make this custom include in a multiple tables query?

**EDIT**

I think I solved it by using `Photo.joins(:girl).includes(:girl => :ad_info).where("photos.approved = 1 and users.profile_approved = 1")`
but when I check the console I have lots of ad_info queries that I should not have.

How can I solve this?
[image: queries that I should not have]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
girl.photos.where.not(info: nil)
```

Comment: I have to query by the photos, so this wouldn't fit my needs. I think I solved the main issue, but the useless queries are still there. Please check my edit

Comment: I know it's not your question. But why do you use a separate info model, it's a one-to-one relation with Girl model, you could just add the columns of the info table to the girl table, it's much simpler.

Comment: I decided to do that because less than 2% of the girls will have that additional info table, so I wanted to avoid lots of null columns. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see why the useless queries are here